# are these partition sizes good?

Tags: partition, setuptools

I was trying to dual boot with Windows 10 and Fedora and could not reclaim the disk that I had shrunk on windows.  After a lot of trial and error, I just deleted everything and installed just Fedora.  But let it automatically choose partition.  After installation. This is what I see upon running fdisk.

I am going to use this computer for java and other such application development, to install eclipse, tomcat , intellij etc.  would this be a good disk partitioning configuration for such things? 
 I have always been a windows user so please let me know if there are important tools and applications I should install that will make my life easy on this platform.  Any tips and suggestions are welcome.

```
/dev/sda1       2048     411647     409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sda2     411648    2508799    2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3    2508800   18874367   16365568   7.8G Linux swap
/dev/sda4   18874368  123731967  104857600    50G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  123731968 1953523711 1829791744 872.5G Linux filesystem
```

Comment: I think this is opinion-based. The default partition configuration should be ok, if you are a n00b, keeping the defaults is good practice, in general, defaults are reasonable. Once you get familiar with the system, you can tweak to your heart's contempt.

Comment: @thecarpy Because the OP is asking we can assume they want to take the reins. There are various qualifiable reasons to partition a certain way to avoid most problems. I'm not sure if fishing for a list of tips is considered to broad here though? Seeking an opinion with a lot of different answers I understand doesn't belong here though.

Comment: Thank you both. I'd like to mark this questions as answered. Don't mean to create opinion thread. However, opinions come from experience and different view points and do help many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always put the swap partition at the end of the disk so its always easy to resize the partition preceding it since you must move partitions proceeding. It should be the same size as your RAM. On modern systems there isn't much need to have any more than that and in most applications except suspend to disk you don't even need that much. So you're setting it to the same size as your RAM primarily to support suspend to disk.

I always make ESP (called EFI system on yours) 512MiBs to future proof it but 200MBs is a good size.

All of your partitions are also 4K aligned which is good.

You appear to have separate /boot and /home partitions. This isn't strictly necessary unless you use Btrfs or RAIDs. But leaving it is fine and Fedora defaults to creating them likely to future proof.

I recommend you partition your system like this:

```
Device     Mount      Size      FS Type Label
/dev/sda1  /boot/efi  512MiB    FAT32   EFI System
/dev/sda2  /boot      1GiB      Ext4    Boot
/dev/sda3  /          50GiB     Ext4    OS
/dev/sda4  /home      893141MiB Ext4    Home
/dev/sda5  -          7991 MiB  swap    -
```

Comment: Thank you @jdwolf for your explanation. Many comments on my question are on hold  I'd like to thank everyone for their response and shared knowledge.